# Randuins Omen/Thornmail and Ruunans Hurricane

Tags: league-of-legends

If you are fighting against someone with Randuins/Thornmail and you have Hurricane then if you shoot their teammate and the extra hurricane shots strike the person with the annoying armour...do you take the bad effects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**YES**

Thronmail Tooltip:

> Unique: On being hit by **basic attacks**, returns 30% of damage, before any reductions such as armor, as magic damage.

Randuin's Omen Tooltip:

> UNIQUE PASSIVE – COLD STEEL: When hit by **basic attacks**, reduces the attacker's attack speed by 15%.

**The second bolts of [Runaan's Hurricane](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Runaan's_Hurricane) are considered basic attacks**. There is also a list in the wiki that tells us what items trigger when damaged by the secondary bolts:

- Doran's Shield
- Ninja Tabi
- Odyn's Veil (only available on Crystal Scar and magic on-hit damage only)
- Thornmail
- Warden's Mail
- Randuin's Omen

Comment: Interesting, this means that if an enemy buys a runaan's it's actually a pretty good counter to buy 2 or 3 thornmails/randuins on your team. And vice versa, when the enemy team has multiple of those items already, buying a runaan's can be pretty bad. Never thought of that.

Comment: @Kevin the randuins passive is only applyed once! even if you hit 3 enemies. you will not have 45% less attackspeed ;-)

Comment: Yes, fortunately it's a *unique* passive.

Comment: So, you guys are saying to just have everyone build a Thornmail so the person with Runaan's kills themselves even faster by attacking you and then a single tank with randuins?  Sounds legit to me.

Comment: @dphil yes... but is it worth? i think not.

Comment: @PhilippSander The same would be asked about someone who actually builds a Runaans to begin with.  My response was mostly a joke but if someone is going Runaans to begin with it's already not worth on their side.  I just assumed it would be a **for fun** game and why not do stuff like that.

Comment: Essentially, hurricane shots apply on-hit effects. @dphil, that's not correct for all champions. For example, Caitlyn's passive charges 3 times as fast in bushes with hurricane if there are 3 targets to hit, allowing her to headshot EVERY SHOT. Combined with lifesteal and traps, you can 1v3.

Comment: @mbomb007 Your comment is about 2 years late.  2 years ago it was really bad item in almost every circumstance.

Comment: @dphil This site is meant to stay up to date, not remain old. The information is here for people NOW to view, not just the OP. Who cares what it was two years ago?

Comment: @mbomb007 Then your comments should address that fact.  Don't call someone out for a comment from 2 years ago.

Comment: If your comment is obsolete, it should be deleted. There's even a flag reason for "obsolete".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but considering thornmail scales with the damage you actually deal (which is insignificant with Runaan's) it won't make much of a difference.

Comment: Unless the rest of your build is damage though

Answer (score -1):

If you have 1 v 1 to yasuo to yasuo if your enemy picks omen and ninja tabi you must pick the trinity force and berserker boots to counter him he cant use a critical damage because trinity force haves more health more lifesteal and counter to the armor you can beat him with face to face skills or it depends if you know how to use combo of yasuo

Comment: not answering the question